# Open link in new tabs but exclude other links

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I can open my links in a different (browser)tab like `<base target='_new' />`

Unfortunately it opens all the links on my page. I really would like to exclude curtain links. How could I do this? (I dont mind javascript/Jquery)

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to mention that the links are set by javascript and are dynamic...Its not physical HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

`<a href="http://example.com/" target="_new">Url</a>`

on every link you want to open in a new tab and not use base target.

Or use e.g. jQery and set a class to every link you don't want to open in a new tab:

`<a href="http://example.com/" class="prevent">Url</a>`

```
$(function(){

    var url;

    $('.prevent').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location = url;
    });

});
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my answer:). I edited my answer to `.live('click',function(e) {` as you said links are created dynamically..

Comment: You do know that there is time setting for accepting anwser..? Anyway thanks for the edit, It now fits even better:)

Comment: Ah right, forgot about the time you have to wait:) Glad I could help:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a base target, you should be setting target on the individual links you want to open into a new tab e.g.

`<a href="#" target="_new">LINK</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use target inside `<a href` or set common class and then set all class' members via javascript.

Comment: How would I do this by Javascript??